# is it correct to use strtotime() to compare dates?

Tags: php

I have some problems with the following:

```
<?php
echo "an issue by the function strtotime"."<br />";
echo "01-30-2011 ======".strtotime(01-30-2011)."<br />";
echo "01/30/2011 ======".strtotime(01/30/2011)."<br />";
echo "07-01-2011 ======".strtotime(07-01-2011)."<br />";
echo "07/01/2011 ======".strtotime(07/01/2011)
?>
```

The result is
an issue by the function strtotime:

```
01-30-2011 ======1310059868
01/30/2011 ======
07-01-2011 ======1310057768
07/01/2011 ======
```

1. Which format is right to give argument to the function strtotime()?
2. Why is the epoch value changing during the page refresh, even though the argument isn't changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't giving `strtotime()` strings!  Put quotes around those parameters first.

```
echo "01-30-2011 ======".strtotime('01-30-2011')."<br />";
echo "01/30/2011 ======".strtotime('01/30/2011')."<br />";
echo "07-01-2011 ======".strtotime('07-01-2011')."<br />";
echo "07/01/2011 ======".strtotime('07/01/2011')
```